NativeBase Progress Component Error: Loss of Precision During Arithmetic Conversion
I am using React Native with NativeBase, and I encountered the following error while rendering the Progress component:
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Loss of precision during arithmetic conversion: (long) 7.000000000000001

...
Code Example:
import React from "react";
import { NativeBaseProvider, Progress } from "native-base";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Progress value={7} />
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

Package Details:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~52.0.23",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.8.0"
  }
}

Error Details:
The error appears to occur because the value prop of the Progress component is being interpreted as a floating-point number (e.g., 7.000000000000001) instead of an integer. This causes an issue with the native implementation on Android, which seems to expect an exact integer (long).
This issue has been tested on Android (tested on the emulator).
